# Multithreading in Javascript using different tabs

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I have done some research because I need to know how multithreading works in javascript, but I'm still missing some things. I have a question:

If I have for example 4 cores in my CPU and I want to run 2 javascript scripts in 2 different tabs in a browser (e.g. in chrome - does it matter if it's chrome or firefox?) is it possible to run them both at the same time using 2 cores?

If the answer is yes - do I need to use Web Workers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes; you need web workers.

Answer (score 2):

You can multithread in JavaScript using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).  You won't need to open other tabs, but you will likely need to have separate JavaScript files.

Most browsers other than IE support web workers.  IE supports it in v10+.  In the past when I implemented web workers, I used web workers client side when available, and fell back to having my web server do the processing otherwise using AJAX as an interface.

Good luck :)